# How to debug autofill complete text box issue

Tags: selenium, autofill

I have an autofill textbox in application for country field i.e when i am writing "In" , it shows all the countries which contains "In". Now when i select any text from drop down let say India, one API is called and that data is getting stored in DB.But my test case is failing because the data which is getting stored is something like this, NULLIndia. Any time i write something in autofill box and select any thing, NULL is getting added there. Due to this my regression suite is failing. How can i fix this issue.

Comment: Do you mean the API data is submitting as `NullIndia` rather `India`?

Comment: Yes . I want API to send India only.